# Why the intermediate variable is limited

Tags: powershell

I want to convert the `Length` unit into `KB`.So I use this command

```
ls | Format-Table Name,@{e={[int]($_.Length/1KB) }; Label="KB"}

Name               KB
----               --
myscript            0
.countline.txt.swp 16
countline.txt      12
LogoTest.xml        0
ping.bat            0
test.ps1            0
test.vbs            0
test1.ps1           0
```

It work normally.But I'm confusing,why I cannot change the variable `e` into another name?such as `xy`?I mean this command will fail

```
ls | Format-Table Name,@{yz={[int]($_.Length/1KB) }; Label="KB"}
```

Actually,when I change the `e` into any name or omit it,the *Powershell* will give error information.Do I have missed any information?

Comment: According to [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) a calculated property has the form `@{Name="Kbytes";Expression={$_.Length / 1Kb}}`, you can abreviate Name and Expression to a single letter, but not alter it completely.  `e` is not a variable.

Comment: @LotPings You save me again/